# Create multiple vectors from list elements and apply a function in R?

Tags: r, patchwork

For this problem, I'm trying to create multiple vectors that I can apply a function on. The function im using is `patchwork::area`.

For example, if I were to explicitly write out a design area to plot using `patchwork` I would do something like this:

```
library(patchwork)

# Explicitly writing out each area
design <- c(
  area(1, 1, 9, 9),
  area(1,10),
  area(2,10),
  area(3,10),
  area(4,10),
  area(5,10),
  area(6,10),
  area(7,10),
  area(8,10),
  area(9,10)
)

# example of what the plot area would look like
plot(design)
```

And this would look like:
[image: example patchwork plot]

Essentially, I am trying to automate the `design` vector above. I attempted this by using `lapply` to create a list of areas, like so:

```
# create some data
vals = seq(1:9)
maxVal <- max(vals)

# use lapply 
areaList <- lapply(vals, function(x) area(x, maxVal+1))
```

This creates a list of the areas, excluding the first row from the `design` object above... but I cant figure out how to turn it into the `design` object above.

A naive attempt (that doesn't work) is to do something like the code below (which tries to include the 1st row of the `design` object)

```
designTest <- c(area(1, 1, maxVal, maxVal), 
                areaList)
```

Any suggestion as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: Does `area()` return a class of object that has a class-specific `c()` function?

Comment: I'm not sure!? I'm not even sure how I would find this out!? The class of, for example, `class(area(1,3))`  is: `patch_area`. But Im not sure if it has a class-specific `c()` function?

Comment: You'd use `?methods` IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the elements of `areaList` like this before plotting:

```
library(patchwork)
library(purrr)

vals = seq(1:9)
maxVal <- max(vals)

areaList <- lapply(vals, function(x) area(x, maxVal+1))
a <- reduce(areaList, c)

plot(a)
```

This should work!

Comment: Such a simple answer for something I've been confused about for hours. Works perfectly. Thanks!